# libGDX progress bar

Tags: java, libgdx, progress-bar

I have only found a couple of topics regarding this and it seems like everything I have is correct, but it doesn't work.

```
public Block(Body body, int x, int y, Player player, GameStage stage, GameScreen screen)
{
    ...

    bar = progressBar();

    stage.addActor(this);
    stage.addActor(bar);
}

public ProgressBar progressBar()
{
    ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle barStyle;
    TextureRegionDrawable textureBar;
    Skin skin = new Skin();

    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(10, 10, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pixmap.fill();

    skin.add("white", new Texture(pixmap));
    textureBar = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("bar.png")));
    barStyle = new ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle(skin.newDrawable("white", Color.DARK_GRAY), textureBar);
    barStyle.knobBefore = barStyle.knob;

    bar = new ProgressBar(0f, maxHitPoints, maxHitPoints/30, false, barStyle);
    bar.setPosition(this.x, this.y);
    bar.setSize(20, 5);
    bar.setAnimateDuration(2);

    return bar;
}

public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha)
{
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

    batch.setColor(blockColor);
    batch.draw(region, this.getX(), this.getY());

    batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    bar.setValue(hitPoints);

}
```

stage.act and stage.draw are called elsewhere but are being called.

I get a solid bar but nothing I try causes it to fill/unfill

I imagine I must be missing something stupid, but for the life of me I can't find out what.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Ha! ya, that might be a good thing to include, whoops, I get a solid bar but nothing I try causes it to fill/unfill.

Comment: Have you tried resizing the `region` that you are drawing? So, just before the call to `batch.draw(region, this.getX(), this.getY())`, try something like `region.setSize(w, h)`, just adjust the width and height as needed.

Comment: Is `maxHitPoints` an int or a float, and what value is it currently?